# Process CloseMainWindow() function doesn't work

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a test method which requires Internet Explorer to be opened and closed numerous times during the test. I have been creating a process like this:

> Process process = Process.Start(...);

And closing it like this:

> process.CloseMainWindow();

However, I have found that I can only call this method once, otherwise I get the error message, "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available".

Once I have closed the process, I would then re-launch Internet Explorer. e.g.

> process = Process.Start(...);

But this didn't work. I also tried nulling the Process variable before calling the Process.Start() method, but this didn't work.

I also tried using process.Kill(), but this caused problems too.

What is the correct way to do this?

UPDATE: Code

```
Process Browser;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestSetup()
{
    Browser = TestBase.LaunchBrowser();

    ...

    Browser.WaitForInputIdle();
    Browser.CloseMainWindow();

    Browser = null
    Browser = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", ...);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
   // do things
   Browser.Kill();
   Browser = Process.Start("IExplore", "www.adifferentwebpage");
}

[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup
{
   Browser.Kill();
}
```

Comment: The arguments to Start() are very important.  Also, Internet Explorer is a single-instance app.  If it is already running then it just asks the first instance to display a new window.  An quits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but it only applies to those who have access to the Coded UI test DLL's (which I believe comes with Visual Studio Ultimate and Premium). 
Therefore I will change the tags on the question.

If you create a Coded UI test project, these DLL references will already be there, but this using reference is what you need:

> using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;

To create a browser window:

> BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("www.whatever.com"));

To close:

> Browser.Close();

This worked no matter how many times I needed to relaunch the browser. This API also includes a multitude of other handy features like the ability to delete cookies, change the URL of the current browser, resize the window etc.

Comment: I tried this and it worked on one machine but not my main Test box.
Browser.Process.Kill(); worked on both my machines.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create another process without reusing the same variable.
Encapsulate your code inside a using statement to properly close and dispose the process variable

```
using(Process process = new Process())
{
    // do you stuff 

    process.Start(.....);

    process.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

Also remember that calling CloseMainWindow doesn't gurantees that the process will close. It only sends a request to close to the main window of the process.  If the application ask for user confirmation before quitting it can refuse to quit.

Comment: How can I guarantee that the window will close? Part of my problem is that the windows won't close.

Comment: You should use process.Kill() but you stated that this has caused other problems. Which?

Comment: It throws a similar error message, that the process has already exited.

Comment: Probably we need to see all of the code around the opening and closing of the process

Comment: I added a code, with just the relevant parts in there. It looked different before, I had replaced using .CloseMainWindow with the .Kill function instead. It always closes and relaunches the first time without any problem, it's just any other time after that it throws errors or doesn't close the window, depending on whether I kill the process or use the CloseMainWindow method.